# Can myhostname and mydomain be identical?

Tags: postfix

I have a domain the sole purpose of which is to be used for email, with Postfix which I'll be running. Let's say its name is `example.com`

Do I understand correctly that I won't have to create a subdomain `mail.example.com`? Because if I did, what would be the purpose of a subdomain?

And `myhostname` and `mydomain` variables will then become identical.

---

Provided that I set up a PTR record correctly, could there be other issues because `myhostname` == `mydomain`? Any issues with spam and deliveribility?

Comment: Although it may seem redundant to create sub-domain DNS records when you only want to see *@example.com e-mail addresses, it is still better to create and use such sub domains. Naming your  server with  `example.com` as the hostname  is not recommended, please use `some-other-hostname.example.com`

Comment: `it is still better to create...` --> How is it better? Or what makes it better?

Answer (score 2):

That is certainly possible. However, you should be aware that there are MXes that try to verify your HELO hostname by DNS lookup (*is the server really the one it claims to be?*). Accordingly, you need to have the `example.com` A record point to your mail server. If you don't want that you risk being rejected by some MXes when trying to pass mail.

I'd always use a subdomain, even if it's `weirdbox.example.com`.

Comment: `I'd always use a subdomain, even if it's weirdbox.example.com.` --> why?

Comment: For the exact reason I stated in the first paragraph. I wouldn't like my 2nd level domain being 'nailed' to my mail server.

Comment: One practical scenario where using a separate hostname is beneficial is switching IP addresses (e.g. moving to different hosting provider). Adding one, later removing another record removes from the equation most of the otherwise to be considered effects of caching in DNS.

Comment: Re-read my question. I've not asked about you, nor what you "would like" or "wouldn't like". What's the PRACTICAL reason in MY case? It doesn't matter what you *would like*.

Comment: @anx how will subdomain "mail." help in that case? Why won't I be able to switch to "mail" subdomain, then revert to my 2nd level domain? That is, vise versa than what I'd do if I had "mail" subdomain initially.

Comment: @pablocamilo Yes on that, the same argument applies to the needless complexity stemming from the change in number of labels though. Since no system is ever static forever, you should not discount migration hazards in your list of "other issues" to be considered.

Comment: @anx I don't understand. Too many of buzz words. "No system", "complex". Re-read my question. I'm asking ONLY about MY case.